# Click event to apply only to container + make querySelectorAll work in IE11

Tags: javascript

The code opens a div/table in fullscreen.

I need the click event to apply to only the containing div so that the fullscreen effect is applied only to the div that has the button (where the click occurred).

Basically the click on the button "View fullscreen table" in the second table should work the same as the button above first table by only modifying the JS script and not the HTML. The second button should open the second table.

https://codepen.io/MistaPrime/pen/jONeKZZ

How to modify click event in that way?

```
var customFullscreen = document.getElementById("fullscreen-table")
        libraryFullscreen = document.getElementById("expand-fullscreen");

    if (customFullscreen && libraryFullscreen) {
        libraryFullscreen.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            if (customFullscreen.requestFullscreen) {
                customFullscreen.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (customFullscreen.msRequestFullscreen) {
                customFullscreen.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (customFullscreen.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                customFullscreen.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (customFullscreen.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                customFullscreen.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
        }, false);
    }
```

EDIT FOR BOUNTY: I got a working solution from @dacre-denny but it does not work in IE11. I would need to somehow make it work in IE11 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that doesn't depend on JQuery would be to revise your HTML and JavaScript as follows (note that although this script is a little bloated, it should be IE11 compatible):

```
  var cancelButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".cancel-fullscreen");

  for (var i = 0; i < cancelButtons.length; i++) {

    var cancelButton = cancelButtons[i];

    cancelButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }, false);
  }

  var tableHolders = document.querySelectorAll(".tableHolder");

  for (var j = 0; j < tableHolders.length; j++) {

    var tableHolder = tableHolders[j];
    var fullScreenButton = tableHolder.querySelector(".view-fullscreen");

    fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (tableHolder.requestFullscreen) {
        tableHolder.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (tableHolder.msRequestFullscreen) {
        tableHolder.msRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (tableHolder.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        tableHolder.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (tableHolder.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        tableHolder.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      }
    }, false);
  }
```

This script requires that the class `cancel-fullscreen` is applied to each "Cancel Fullscreen" button in this way:

```
<button id="cancel-fullscreen" class="cancel-fullscreen">Cancel fullscreen</button>
```

For a full working version, see the code snippet below - hope that helps!

```js
(function() {

  var cancelButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".cancel-fullscreen");

  for (var i = 0; i < cancelButtons.length; i++) {

    var cancelButton = cancelButtons[i];

    cancelButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }, false);
  }

  var tableHolders = document.querySelectorAll(".tableHolder");

  for (var j = 0; j < tableHolders.length; j++) {

    var tableHolder = tableHolders[j];
    var fullScreenButton = tableHolder.querySelector(".view-fullscreen");

    fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (tableHolder.requestFullscreen) {
        tableHolder.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (tableHolder.msRequestFullscreen) {
        tableHolder.msRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (tableHolder.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        tableHolder.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (tableHolder.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        tableHolder.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      }
    }, false);
  }

})();
```

```css
.tableHolder {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableHolder" id="fullscreen-table">
  <button id="expand-fullscreen" class="view-fullscreen">View fullscreen table</button>
  <button id="cancel-fullscreen" class="cancel-fullscreen">Cancel fullscreen</button>

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <caption>FIRST TABLE</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>HEADER</th>
      <th>HEADER</th>
      <th>HEADER</th>
      <th>HEADER</th>
      <th>HEADER</th>
      <th>HEADER</th>
      <th>HEADER</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEXT</td>
      <td>TEXT</td>
      <td>TEXT</td>
      <td>TEXT</td>
      <td>TEXT</td>
      <td>TEXT</td>
      <td>TEXT</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>



<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>



<div class="tableHolder" id="fullscreen-table">
  <button id="expand-fullscreen" class="view-fullscreen">View fullscreen table</button>
  <button id="cancel-fullscreen" class="cancel-fullscreen">Cancel fullscreen</button>

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <caption>FIRST TABLE</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>HEADER 2</th>
      <th>HEADER 2</th>
      <th>HEADER 2</th>
      <th>HEADER 2</th>
      <th>HEADER 2</th>
      <th>HEADER 2</th>
      <th>HEADER 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEXT 2</td>
      <td>TEXT 2</td>
      <td>TEXT 2</td>
      <td>TEXT 2</td>
      <td>TEXT 2</td>
      <td>TEXT 2</td>
      <td>TEXT 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Waw ! That is it ! Thank you for that. Now that I see it, it is so simple it's beautiful.

Comment: @MistaPrime if you've found this answer helpful, please mark accepted by clicking the grey tick

Comment: Also do you know why your solution does not work with IE 11 ?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to make it work with IE11 ?

Comment: My mistake - looks like there was a typo on this line `else if (tableHolder.msRequestFullScreen)` , which should have been `else if (tableHolder.msRequestFullscreen)`. Just updated answer - hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm afraid that it is still not it. Is it working for you in IE11 on Windows 10?

Comment: Sorry about that, I double checked and IE11 does not provide a `msRequestFullScreen()` but instead provides `msRequestFullscreen()`. I've just updated the answer - does that work for you?

Comment: It still does not work in IE 11. I am guessing you must be on a Mac, is that why you cannot detect IE 11 or test on it?

Comment: @MistaPrime querySelectorAll() is supported in IE11. What is NOT tho is `const` in for-of-loops, so you might have to replace those with `var`s.

Comment: I changed it to var and it still fails in IE11.  Is it working for you in IE 11 ?

Comment: Just a small note:  the function(**evt**) is not used. The **evt** is not necessary. I removed it. Still works great !

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse up the hierarchy and find the closest div (see jQuery.closest if you are able to use jQuery).

```
function eventHandler(e) {
  //normally, 'this' points to the element that was clicked
  //but if not, you can use e.target
  var parent = this;
  while (parent.tagName != 'div') {
    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: HTML `tagName`s are in all caps. [`.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) isn't just for jQuery.